# Are there good manuals for developer using Umbraco to create website?

Tags: umbraco, manual

I'm relatively new to Umbraco and even web development. After a period about one month taken to get started with Umbraco, I feel now dissapointed about Umbraco in the aspect of its available written studying stuff. Only very outdated and messy stuff can be found over its official website. This makes everyone new to it very hard getting started with Umbraco, let alone become an expert at it. But I was asked to development a websit of small-to-middle size using Umbraco. Can any kind fellow help me: tell me where I can find good manuals for developer using Umbraco to create website?